# Alternative to RadScriptManager for scripts Bundling

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

Is there any alternative for RadScriptManager for combining scripts? . I'm using latest AjaxControlToolKit and Telerik controls which are causing issues in my code if i'm using RadScriptManager. So I have replaced RadScriptManager with AjaxControlTookKitScriptManager , now I need a solution for combining script files of telerik on page load as I cannot combine scripts using AjaxControlToolKit for Telerik . Please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need better caching, so you can consider the scripts CDN offered by Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html. Caveat: it requires RadScriptManager, so the AJaxControlToolkit controls will break, because they do not work with any asp:ScriptManager but their own (bummer).

Option 2 is to create combined files by following this article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-disabling-embedded-resources.html. If you know the controls you use, copy the needed scripts and use some other tool to combine them (or do it manually).

I think there is (or is going to be) some combined script file for all the controls offered OOB, but you should ask them about that. If(when) it is available, use the second option to add this script to your page(s)

Comment: Thank You... I'm going for second option

Comment: AjaxToolKit has CompositeScripts tag, if we place the required scripts in this tag it will generate single axd file